# Matlab: Moving Light Source

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 3-D plot of a shaded 3-D object. When the user rotated the plot, how do I make the light source constantly update to be from the direction the user is looking from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at MATLAB's `camlight` command ([online documentation](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camlight.html)).

Here's a minimal demo to get you started:

```
function camlight_demo
    % some example data to plot
    surf(peaks);
    h = rotate3d;
    set(h,'Enable','on');

    % add a light
    LightSource = camlight('headlight');

    % add a callback which will be executed after each rotation
    set(h,'ActionPostCallback',{@move_light_source, LightSource});
end

% This function will move the light after each rotation
function move_light_source(src, evt, LightSource)
    camlight(LightSource, 'headlight');
end
```